# jquery selectall not function properly after deselect

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selectall

I need a solution about my problem.
I load my page, click on my first checkbox and all checkbox are checked. Great!
After I repeat the operation, deselect first checkbox and all checkbox are deselected. Great!

But if I click again on the first checkbox, nothing happens apparently, but with firebug I see that each checkbox is checked, but it does not appear as checked.

Can you help me?

My code:

```
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
    $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function () {
    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

[here a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mosaic78/TH4m4/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

to

```
$('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TH4m4/2/)

[**More information here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: GREAT! What the difference between attr and prop ?

Comment: @Scream welcome :). [read difference here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)